# Custom UIView with IBDesignable UIView inside not showing in app

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ibdesignable

I'm trying to create a `UIView` with this style:

[image]

I made the circles using an `@IBDesignable` class, using the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52333564/2180785):

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CircleView: UIView {
    private var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    @IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor = .blue {
        didSet {
            shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        configure()
    }

    private func configure() {
        shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds).cgPath
    }
}
```

So, I made another `UIView`, let's call it `DotsView` that contains both the `UILabel` on top, and a horizontal `UIStackView`, when I'm on that xib file, the circles are showing up correctly.

Then in my `UIStoryboard` I have a `UIViewController`, where I place my custom `UIView` (`DotsView`), and set its class to it, on both the xib for `DotsView` as well as the storyboard, like so:

[image]

And while I know, the dots aren't going to show up on the storyboard as they are "wrapped" in my `DotsView`, they should appear on my simulator when run, which isn't the case.

Am I missing something in order to show this custom view?

This is the `DotsView` class, nothing removed:

```
import UIKit

class DotsView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var firstDigitDot: CircleView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondDigitDot: CircleView!
    @IBOutlet weak var thirdDigitDot: CircleView!
    @IBOutlet weak var fourthDigitDot: CircleView!
    
    //initWithFrame to init view from code
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }
      
    //initWithCode to init view from xib or storyboard
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }
      
    //common func to init our view
    private func setupView() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DotsView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    }
}
```

I edited the above code for the `DotsView`, according to this [tutorial](https://medium.com/better-programming/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960).

But now, the app is crashing:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x600003120ca0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key contentView.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I have set my File's owner to the `DotsView`, but I'm unsure on why this is happening now

My xib's file name is `DotsView.xib` as well

Comment: If `DotsView` depends on a XIB file, that file won't be loaded when you use `DotsView` in a storyboard. It will just instantiate an instance of that class; there is no automatic link to a XIB file. You would need to either load the view from the XIB file yourself in the `DotsView` `init` or make`DotsView` also `@IBDesignable` and have it create its view hierarchy programmatically

Comment: Actually while trying to solve this issue, I came across this [tutorial](https://medium.com/better-programming/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960), been trying to make it work, I was about to make an edit on the post when I receive the notification, right timing I guess...

Comment: @Paulw11 just edited the question with some extra details, I'm sure that's what you meant with *"You would need to either load the view from the XIB file yourself in the `DotsView` `init`"*

Comment: Nevermind, I was testing a change I saw in the comments where it had the owner as `nil`, it seemed strange, but I gave it a try and forgot to change it back to `self` after testing other things. It's now being displayed correctly. Would you like adding your comment as an answer Paul?

Comment: You should probably switch to the [non-deprecated function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1402909-loadnibnamed) and access the view from the array.  Personally I wouldn't bother with the NIB file; You can just set up a stack view programmatically, make `DotsView` `@IBDesignable` and then you will see your dots in the storyboard.  It is probably better to use an array for your circles (Use a reference collection in the XIB file) rather than 4 discrete properties

Comment: Adding a reference collection is something I didn't know about. But I guess for a simple UIView like this one, it would be better to make it programmatically. I was just trying to avoid that, it's been a while since I last made one. Thanks for all the help so far