# How to show the standard number keyboard without a UITextField in Swift on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

I'm trying to show the standard's number keyboard when the user gets to my `ViewController`, and be able to capture user's input to fill some circles that are on the UI each time the user enters a number, the circles in question are the ones I show on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65974883/2180785).

[image]

How can I do that? All the question that I've already read suggest using `UIKeyInput` protocol to display a custom keyboard, but that's not what I'm trying to do. One of those is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13005969/2180785).

The code I came up with, after checking the above post, was this one, but after a lot of reading and discussing, this was for having the above's `UIView` as my custom keyboard and I'm unsure how to make it right.

---

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var dotsView: DotsView!
    
    var keyInputView: KeyInputView = KeyInputView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        keyInputView.inputView = dotsView
        keyInputView.becomeFirstResponder()
        //self.view.addSubview(keyInputView) //In the XIB, the view is set to be displayed in center vertically and horizontally. If we uncomment this line, the view is pushed downwards.
    }
}
```

**DotsView**

```
import UIKit

class DotsView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var digitDots: [CircleView]!
    
    //initWithFrame to init view from code
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }
      
    //initWithCode to init view from xib or storyboard
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }
      
    //common func to init our view
    private func setupView() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DotsView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    }
}
```

**CircleView**

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CircleView: UIView {
    private var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    @IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor = .blue {
        didSet {
            shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        configure()
    }

    private func configure() {
        shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds).cgPath
    }
}
```

**KeyInputView**

```
import UIKit

class KeyInputView: UIView {
   var _inputView: UIView?

   override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { return true }
   override var canResignFirstResponder: Bool { return true }

   override var inputView: UIView? {
       set { _inputView = newValue }
       get { return _inputView }
   }
}

// MARK: - UIKeyInput
//Modify if need more functionality
extension KeyInputView: UIKeyInput {
    var hasText: Bool {
        return false
    }
    
    func insertText(_ text: String) {
        
    }
    
    func deleteBackward() {
        
    }
}
```

As for the XIBs you can access them in [this repo](https://github.com/Frakcool/ShowKeyboardExample)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to make your `DotsView` conform to `UIKeyInput`...

```
class DotsView: UIView, UIKeyInput {
    
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var digitDots: [CircleView]!
    
    //initWithFrame to init view from code
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }
      
    //initWithCode to init view from xib or storyboard
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }
      
    //common func to init our view
    private func setupView() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DotsView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    }

    var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType {
        get {
            return .numberPad
        }
        set {}
    }

    // required by UIKeyInput protocol
    var hasText: Bool = false

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        true
    }
    
    func insertText(_ text: String) {
        print("Number tapped:", text)
        // do something with the number that was tapped
    }
    
    func deleteBackward() {
        print("Delete Backward tapped")
        // do something because Delete was tapped
    }
}
```

Then change your `viewDidLoad()` in `ViewController` to:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dotsView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Now, you have no need for an additional `KeyInputView`.

Comment: This works, I had just forgotten to toggle the keyboard after trying your solution